# How does the fractional Fourier transform apply to an out-of-focus imaging system? Do we use the fractional distance to the focal plane?

Tags: optics, mathematical-physics, fourier-transform

In [Fourier optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_optics) it is sometimes convenient to think of lenses as "Fourier transformers". For an imaging system between two planes with a pupil in the center, the amplitude in the pupil is the FT of the image.

A simple way to think about this is that a lens swaps angles and positions (for a plane at the focal distance); all rays from *a given position* on the focal plane will have the *same angle* at the lens pupil and vice-versa.

Mathematically there is the [fractional Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Fourier_transform) $F_{\alpha}(x)$ and when $\alpha = \pi/2$ this is the normal or "continuous" Fourier transform.

**Question:** How does the fractional Fourier transform apply to an out-of-focus imaging system? For example, if I measure the amplitude at 90% of the distance to the focal plane, would it be reproduced by taking the fractional Fourier transform of the amplitude in the pupil using $\alpha = 0.9 \pi/2$? Is it as simple as that?

Related and potentially helpful:

- [Fractional Fourier Transform and Fresnel Propagation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/486281/83380)
- [What is an intuitive explanation of Gouy phase?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71/83380)
- Wikipedia: [Gaussian beam optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam) might be the simplest approach to answering here as well.
- JOSA A: [Fractional Fourier optics](https://www.osapublishing.org/josaa/abstract.cfm?uri=josaa-12-4-743)
- Optik: [Fractional Fourier transform in optics – a new perspective](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0030402604703332)
- Optica Applicita: [Fractional Fourier transform in optical setups](https://dbc.wroc.pl/Content/41401/PDF/optappl_2803p227.pdf)

Comment: It looks like propagation of light is related to the generalization of the Fractional Fourier Transform: The linear canonical transformation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_canonical_transformation. The quadratic phase shift that light picks up (as a function of propagation direction and distance) looks to be related to the $a$ and $d$ parameters in the linked article.